# pywinauto: Unable to locate elements in access database form

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to locate a button in an access data form and invoke it i continue to get an error element cannot be found 'ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'Monthly', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': , 'backend': 'uia'}'

```
import os
import subprocess
from pywinauto import Desktop
filename = r'C:\Users\Desktop\SW.accdb'
accessPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.exe'
subprocess.Popen([accessPath,filename])
dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Access - SW *')
#dlg.window(best_match='Monthly')
print(dlg.Workspace.frmMainMenu.print_control_identifiers())
```

I get this result
Control Identifiers:

```
Dialog - 'frmMainMenu'    (L636, T284, R1567, B705)
['frmMainMenuDialog', 'frmMainMenu', 'Dialog']
child_window(title="frmMainMenu", auto_id="1120", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Pane - ''    (L647, T673, R1556, B694)
   | ['', 'Pane', '0', '1', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   | child_window(auto_id="4", control_type="Pane")
   | 
   | Pane - ''    (L647, T324, R1556, B423)
   | ['2', 'Pane2']
   | 
   | Pane - ''    (L647, T424, R1556, B673)
   | ['3', 'Pane3']
   | 
   | TitleBar - ''    (L645, T293, R1558, B322)
   | ['4', 'TitleBar']
```

When i try using all the Pane values to check where the button Monthly is located and I get this error.

ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'Monthly', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': , 'backend': 'uia'}

I tried using dlg.child_window(title="Monthly",class_name="Button") i get a result pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification at 0x217d84cbf60>. Now i am not sure why the element not found error shows up.

[image]

I checked the properties of the button in the access database i have noticed that Monthly is available and it reflects as toggle button, i tried toggle button as well and it was not found.

How do i avoid this error.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Can `Inspect.exe` see this button?

Comment: If yes, probably the button is a child of another higher level element. If no, you're maybe out of luck with pywinauto and any other GUI automation tool. But MS Access provides good COM interface that can be used with `win32com.client` module included into pyWin32 package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it can be done.  Access is an event driven architecture not an executable.

What can be done is to write & trigger the same code as behind that button, from another object within Access including a module.  But I don't think you can remotely trigger the button itself.